# L’expression « être foison » existe-t-elle ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

J’emploie plus ou moins fréquemment la construction « être foison » (en général, « ne pas être foison », à vrai dire).

> La chorale est un peu déséquilibrée, mais que veux-tu, les bons ténors ne sont pas foison.

Je ne trouve cependant pas de référence ou de citation reprenant cet emploi. Est-il incorrect ?

Answer (score 7):

Foison signifie *grande abondance* et ne s'emploie pas de cette façon. En revanche, on peut dire :

- il n'y a pas foison de bons ténors (vieilli, dit le Trésor).
- les bons ténors, il n'y en a pas à foison (la locution *à foison* me semble plus courante que *foison* tout seul).
- les bons ténors ne sont pas légion.

Answer (score 1):

J’ai trouvé trace de l’expression dans le [Dictionnaire du Moyen Français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/foison?idf=dmfXdXrmXfoc;str=0) :

> A.1. […] *Estre (grand) foison.* "Être (très) nombreux" […]
> 2. […] *Estre foison.* "Être en grande quantité"

Ce qui ne dit pas grand chose de son usage contemporain. On constate que « sont foison » se répand [grâce à Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+foison&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=19&smoothing=3), mais je ne sais pas comment étendre la recherche à d’autres conjugaisons du verbe être et l’usage semble encore fort restreint.

Comment: [Comme ça](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=être_INF+foison&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3) mais il n'y a qu'un résultat :-)